# JSON.stringify is not storing object property values

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I have the following object in my code:

```
/* ======= Model ======= */
    model = {
        workout: [
            {
                name: '',
                email: '',
                workouttype: '',
                workoutplan: '',
                excardio: '',
                exstrength: '',
                excore: '',
                exhiit: '',
                validworkout: false,
                hasexercises: false
            }
        ]
    };
```

When I try to save the object to localstorage, all the properties are empty.

Here is how I'm storing my object:

```
saveWorkout: function () {
    var key = "Workout",
        item = JSON.stringify(model.workout);
    localStorage.setItem(key, item);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Erm, works for me. Are you sure you're doing it right? Is `model` in-scope for `saveWorkout`?

Comment: aint all the properties empty in the example?

Comment: In other parts of my code, I'm updating the values.  To keep this post short, I left those part out of the example.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/muwoloxixu/edit?js,console - seems to work, as I said.

Comment: You need to provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem. The code you've posted isn't enough.

Comment: `stringify` would skip undefined values, by the way, is that possibly related to the problem?